# spring JPA save can't store data into the db

Tags: java, spring

User:

```
@Data

@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PUBLIC, force=true)

@RequiredArgsConstructor

@Entity

@Table(name="user")

public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="username")
    private final String username;
    
    @Column(name="password")
    private final String password;
    
    
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    
}
```

And Repository:

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long>{
}

And I want to add User through registerprocess

```
    @PostMapping
    @Transactional
    public String registerprocess(@ModelAttribute Register reg,Model model,User user) {
        userRepo.save(reg.toUser(passwordEncoder));
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
```

But the save can't store the User data into the database,I can't find what it go wrong.
I follow the book to do ,but I can't get the same result.Can anyone help me what I should do
to solve this problem?Or Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: whats your application properties file like? is the sql mode set to update?

Comment: "But the save can't store..." - what do you mean by this?  Is it throwing an Exception?  Does it appear to complete but there is no data in the database when you look?

Comment: It isn't throwing an Exception,but I can't see the data I store into.

Comment: spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
# For MySQL connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PRODUCT?serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.http.encoding.force=true

Comment: turn on hibernate logs via application properties, e.g.:
`logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: TRACE
`

And you can try to save and flush changes to synchronize your db with current state

Comment: and no need to use Transactional on controller method because it is creates automatically if spring open-in-view property turned on (it's true by default).

Comment: why I need to turn on hibernate logs via application properties?